# How can I test an app that uses Firebase, with large amounts of data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

We're building a Flutter/Dart/Firebase app, and we want to test it with a large amount of user data. Is there a recommended way to add Firebase collections with thousands of items per user (and we're also storing an image for each item in the collection in Firebase Storage)?  We like to use the actual network-based Firestore rather than a local emulator so we can factor in network transmission times for the images.

I assume we would need to create separate test database (and storage) instances...is the right way to go about it?  And then, what about importing mass data? I was hoping to find an extension for that, but no luck.  :-)

I haven't been able to find a straightforward solution to testing with large amounts of data in Firebase.  Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Firestore does not offer any way to "bulk add" documents to Firestore or "bulk add" files to Storage. I also have no knowledge of the existence of a [Firebase Extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions) that does that.

If you don't want to use the emulator, then the only option that you have is to add that large amount of data yourself. So you have to write code that adds those documents/files individually to the Firebase servers. This operation can be done from the client-side code, or you can add it using [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions).

However, keep in mind that when it comes to Firestore, there is a facility to [batch writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes), but unfortunately, it's limited to 500 documents per batch. So you should take advantage of this feature. Also, keep in mind that there is currently no way to bypass [quota limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) to import data sets.

I suggest you read the following:

- [Documentation on best practices for read and write operations](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#read_and_write_operations)
- [Designing for scale](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#designing_for_scale)

Considering these resources, please see that there is really no faster way to add large amounts of data into Firestore. Firestore is not optimized for fast writes, it's optimized for incredibly **fast** reads.

Comment: Thanks, Alex, this gives me a few things to look at, for sure.